# Access Custom HTML Element methods in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using a framework similar to bootstrap in Angular that provides custom HTML elements, like , and I want to update the table with a click of the button. In my typescript file, I have code to get the element

```
(<HTMLTableElement>document.getElementById("resultTable")).updateRows()
```

and the issue I'm getting is that when I cast it to a HTMLElement, the methods that are predefined such as updateRows() don't work, and I get the error message that Property updateRows doesn't exist on HTML Element. Is there a way for me to call the custom methods so I can use the custom elements? Thanks so much!

```
(<HTMLTableElement>document.getElementById("resultTable")).updateRows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not view child?

First add a reference to the html element in the `component.html` file

```
<result-table #resultTable>...</result-table>
```

Then you can get that element using `viewChild`

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    @ViewChild('resultTable') resultTable: ElementRef<any>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const element = this.resultTable && this.resultTable.nativeElement ?  this.resultTable.nativeElement: this.resultTable;
        element.updateRows();
    }
```